# Laravel Capture Query event

Tags: php, laravel, events, model

I'm trying to capture an event when ever the application runs  `select` query.

So lets say i have `ProductsModel`

and when ever method `ProductsModel::all();` runs, i want to fire an event.

I have tried using `Observers` but it didnt work, the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events 
says it cannot do such thing.

Is there any way I can achieve this using `EventListeners` or perhaps somehow extending the available events? ?